# Refactoring project structure in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, refactoring

Say I have a class library project that I feel is getting too large and unwieldy and I want to break it out into smaller class library projects for easier distribution and deployment. Is there a way in VS2012 to use the refactor capability to accomplish this seamlessly?

So for example say my assembly has an IO package that I want to move to it's own project, so right now it might be:

```
MyAssembly.IO.Readers
MyAssembly.IO.Writers
etc
```

and I want to refactor all my references to have it in a different project completely (e.g.
MyIOSpecificAssembly). Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), you could drag-n-drop the file to another project (while holding SHIFT to *move* instead of *copy*), then use the [adjust namespaces](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) refactoring.

ReSharper also has various other refactorings that might be useful in this context, such as [moving](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Move.html) a type to another file, folder or namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will take a look at that for sure